# Search for files whose names match a patern in batch script

Tags: batch-file, find

I want to obtain the list of files from all the directories. Having a hierarchy like that:

```
all_directories/dir_cc
all_directories/dir_dd

all_directories/dir_cc/swt/file{1..n}.txt
all_directories/dir_cc/swd/file{1..n}.txt

all_directories/dir_dd/swt/file{1..n}.txt
all_directories/dir_dd/swd/file{1..n}.txt
```

I need to obtain recursively a list with the files from swt directory. This is what I want to obtain:

```
all_directories/dir_cc/swt/file{1..n}.txt
all_directories/dir_dd/swt/file{1..n}.txt
```

This is an example but my hierarchy is much larger.
In linux I do this:

```
find all_directories -regex ".*/dir_.*/swt
```

In windows batch how can I do the same thing, or ony with iterating throug all with for?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dir /a-d /s /b "c:\all_directories" | findstr /i /r /c:"\\dir_[^\\]*\\swt\\."
```

Generate a recursive listing of files and filter to get only the required

To use into a `for` command

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (
    'dir /a-d /s /b "c:\all_directories" ^| findstr /i /r /c:"\\dir_[^\\]*\\swt\\."'
) do (
    echo %%f
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative: it assumes that all the file{*}.txt files have numerals in the * portion.

```
dir "all_directories\file{*}.txt" /b /s /a-d|find /i "\swt\file"
```